# Is it possible to let one Thread just acquire one permit of a Semaphore till the next release?

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I use Semaphore:

```java
 private Semaphore sem_Container = new Semaphore(3, true);
```

and 2 Threads share the permits. A third thread does nothing else then releasing the semaphore.

Now it happens, that sometimes one of the two reader threads does not get one permit in one period.

See this log:

```
//Period1
D/Td_GetNewData_VM_MA
D/Td_GetNewData_VM_MA
D/Td_GetNewData_VM_M
//Period2
D/Td_GetNewData_VM_MA
D/Td_GetNewData_VM_MA
D/Td_GetNewData_VM_MA
//Period3
D/Td_GetNewData_VM_M
D/Td_GetNewData_VM_MA
D/Td_GetNewData_VM_MA
```

I think what is happening in my example is that one thread calls the `acquire()` three times in a row, because the other thread has not been executed by the system in that time...

Since "fair" only means that the semaphore just makes sure that the longest waiting Thread in the Queue gets a permit, is it also possible to make sure that every thread gets one? Or at least every thread can just acquire one?

Comment: You might want to look into using a [`CyclicBarrier`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) instead.

Comment: It seems like a good idea, but I can't see this in my context, especially because I have sometimes running 1 to 3 Threads reading. My (when working) system also makes sure, that after 3 times reading, the semaphore is blocked till the next release. Can you give me an example maybe?

Comment: Are you `release`ing the semaphore on exit?

Comment: @JohnVint the third thread calls `release` after updating some values in the container the semaphore is needed for.